# Conditional load redux devServer

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-devtools

I would like to add redux devTools to the store *only* if the local server is up. Because this is an async operation I end up with an 'incomplete' store.

The async function which checks if the server is there:

```
export async function isReduxDevServerAlive(url,port, secure = false) {
const server = secure ? 'https' : 'http' + `://${url}:${port}`;
try {
    let response = await fetch(server);
    return true;
} catch(error) {
    return false;
}
```

The `store.js` script

```js
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import devTools from 'remote-redux-devtools';
import { isReduxDevServerAlive } from './util/dev'
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, combineReducers, compose } from 'redux';

import * as reducers from './reducers';
import * as constants from './constants';

let composable = [ applyMiddleware(thunk) ];
const reducer = combineReducers(reducers);

if(isReduxDevServerAlive(constants.REDUX_DEV_SERVER, constants.REDUX_DEV_SERVER_PORT))
{
    composable.push(
        devTools({
            name: 'EPP app', realtime: true,
            hostname: constants.REDUX_DEV_SERVER, port: constants.REDUX_DEV_SERVER_PORT,
            maxAge: 30, filters: {blacklist: ['EFFECT_RESOLVED']}
        })
    );
}

const bconfigureStore = (c) => {
        return createStore(reducer,{},compose(...c));
}

export default function configureStore() {
    return bconfigureStore(composable);
}
```

The script should wait to export till when it knows if the server is up or down. Could you help me out how to accomplish this?

Comment: Well that should work for as long as you hold with final execution of the configureStore() function until you determine if server is up or not. Another thing that springs to mind - maybe use redux dev tools chrome extension instead of dev tools package.

Answer (score 0):

You have just to make your `configureStore` function asynchronous and apply the render in a callback, for example, as we're doing [here](https://github.com/zalmoxisus/crossbuilder/blob/master/src/app/index.js).

However, you could just set `realtime` to `false` and have an action to start monitoring, specified for `startOn` parameter (which you dispatch explicitly or if local server is 'up'). In this case you will not have to restart the application in order to start monitoring. The only downside is that [`redux-devtools-instrument`](https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-instrument) will still store the history, it doesn't affect the performance significantly, but can consume RAM in case you have large objects in the states. We could add the ability to start/stop instrumentation there.